# Cannot get body of ServerRequest in ExceptionHandler because of unsupported media type

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive

I want test out the exception handler by doing the following:

- send a request with an XML payload that can be unmarshalled as a valid object in my app
- throw arbitrary error to trigger the ExceptionHandler
- send a ServerResponse with body that is the same as ServerRequest payload

When I try to do this, I get an error on my bodyToMono(String.class) request:

`Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=java.lang.String`

here is my Exception handler:

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
public class ExceptionResolver extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    public ExceptionResolver(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ResourceProperties resourceProperties, ApplicationContext applicationContext, ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        super(errorAttributes, resourceProperties, applicationContext);
        this.setMessageWriters(configurer.getWriters());
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(
            ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return RouterFunctions
                .route(RequestPredicates.all(), request ->
                        request.bodyToMono(String.class).log()
                        .doOnError(e -> {
                            System.out.println("errored :(");
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }).flatMap(r -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).syncBody(r)));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  I expect that any kind of payload could be extracted as a String.class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is quite simple regarding the error message. You are trying to return the response as appication/json, perhaps because you are adding content-type header to the response or because the default content type of the response is this, but you are trying to return an xml that does not fit into a json schema, and it crashes

Comment: let me rephrase the question, I just want to get the body of the ServerRequest

Comment: I think the problem could be because with getRoutingFunction you can only response in json format as is explained in documentation and you are trying to return an xml format: 

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.html

Comment: That's exactly it!.  Thanks!  Now on to finding a way to return an xml payload :(